# Form fields overflow Bootstrap form

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am playing around with Bootstrap grid framework in my simple form. For some reason the form fields seem to overflow the form border box. See image below.

[image]
This doesn't make sense because all my form field elements are inside the form. My html is here. I have made sure to import Bootstrap css and Bootstrap js.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <form class="col-md-8 form">
                <h4 class="form-heading">A form</h4>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class = "col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="input1" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="input2" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "col-md-12">
                        <textarea name="terms" rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css is here.

```
.form {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: solid black;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    float: none;
}

.form .form-heading {
    text-align: center;
}

.form .form-control {
    position: relative;
}

input {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Please share any ideas on a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the columns `float` which is typically remedied by using `row`s as far as Bootstrap goes. You are nesting columns while only using a single `row` for all these levels of columns you have. I would either use additional rows or clear the float yourself with CSS. And you probably don't need the outer most column.

And this doesn't make much sense either: `<form class="col-md-8 form">`. You form class has its width set at **100%** but your using a column that is set at width **66.66666667%** by default. And `form-control` has a default width of 100% also.

[Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/)

**Working Example:**

```css
.form {
  border: solid black;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <form class="form">

        <h4 class="form-heading text-center">A Form</h4>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="input1" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="input2" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="terms" rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding height: 1000px to form class

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    .form {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: solid black;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 1000px;
    float: none;
}

.form .form-heading {
    text-align: center;
}

.form .form-control {
    position: relative;
}

input {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
    </style>
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <form class="col-md-8 form">
                <h4 class="form-heading">A form</h4>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class = "col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="input1" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="input2" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "col-md-12">
                        <textarea name="terms" rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>

<script>


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

col-md only will work at screen with medium sizes so if you resize your nav screen you will see everything is ok but if you want to keep the same look at all screen you only have to use col-lg-

Example:
'

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <form class="col-lg-8 form">
                <h4 class="form-heading">A form</h4>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class = "col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" name="input1" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" name="input2" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "col-lg-12">
                        <textarea name="terms" rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

'

https://jsfiddle.net/8n8wdsvj/